# Dynamic text on title decorations

Tags: qgis, python, expression, dynamic

I am attempting to display in QGIS a numerical value taken from the attribute table of a particular scene and display it in the top right corner of the project layer.

So far I have been successful in being able to preview the value in the attribute table

```
aggregate('scene','array_agg',"gfs_speed_av")
```

[image: expression preview]

However the value previewed does not show up in the title decorations.

I have also tried this expression below which just displays the expression as text

```
to_string(aggregate('scene','array_agg',"gfs_speed_av"))
```

[image: see below]

Why isn't my first expression displaying like shown in the preview tab?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: @PolyGeo QGIS  .

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification.

Comment: Try to enclose your expression in an `eval()` function: `eval ( [your expression] )`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first expression creates an array, as you can see in the preview: `[4.26]`. To get the (first) value, use either:

- [index operator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-index) `[0]` at the end of the expression: `aggregate('scene','array_agg',"gfs_speed_av")[0]`
- or use function [`array_to_string()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-to-string), not `to_string()`

If only the expression in string form is shown in the result, evaluate it (convert the string to functions) using function [`eval()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#eval): `eval ( [your expression] )` to get the calculated outpug.

Comment: Thank you. Your first solution done the trick

Comment: You're welcome. As a new user, please be adviced that the policy of this site is to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235